# Правильный множественный MySQL-запрос в node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, почему вылетает ошибка:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '?),(1, ?),(1, ?)' at line 1

И, возможно, мои 'костыли' - это не лучший вариант создания запроса...

```
//Подготавливаем запрос для жанров
 var querygenre = 'INSERT INTO `genre_novel` (`novel_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES ';
      for (temp_genre in req.body.genre) {        
        querygenre += '('+req.params.idnovel+', ?),';
      }
      querygenre = querygenre.substring(0, querygenre.length - 1);
      //Получается INSERT INTO `genre_novel` (`novel_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (1, ?), (2, ?) и т.д.

pool.query(' DELETE FROM `genre_novel` WHERE novel_id = ?; '+querygenre+' ', [req.params.idnovel, req.body.genre]
        , function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) return next(err);
```

Comment: У меня с пост запросом приходит массив, из которого:
1)Нужно обновить книгу (Описание, заголовки и т.д.)
2)И из другой таблицы нужно обновить жанры у этой книги.

Для пункта 2, самым простым мне показалось следующее: удалить все жанры, принадлежащие книге и вставить полученные пост запросом, что я собственно и пытаюсь сделать.

Возможно есть способ попроще, но я о нём не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем просто используйте pool.escape.

```
    arrGenre.forEach (function(item, i, arrGenre) {        
        querygenre += '('+pool.escape(req.params.idnovel)+', '+pool.escape(item)+'),';
      });
```